# Mac: Apple dock bouncing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a bouncing effect of a bar.
If you have noticed in mac, the dock where all the applications are lined up. The minute you click on any of the application, the icon starts bouncing. I am looking for similar effect.
The bar needs to bounce 3 times and then stop for a second or two and again bounce 3 times.

Here is what I am doing currently which didn't help

```
$(function () {
function bounceDiv(){
    $("#six").effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:20 }, 400);
}
setInterval(bounceDiv,1000);
});
```

Thanx in Advance.

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-bounce-effect-bounce-html-js/

Comment: it works when page loads

Comment: @anaida Surround the `bounceDiv` with quotes this way: `'bounceDiv()'`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can try *Fantastic Bouncy Effect using jQuery/JavaScript*

[image]

Our Goal will be to create a HTML page that has 4 boxes (DIVs). Clicking each of these boxes will bounce them is a particular direction. We can control the direction as well as the speed of bouncing element with arguments to the method of jQuery.

#### HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><div id="bouncy1">Click here to bounce. Direction: Up</div></td>
    <td><div id="bouncy2">Click here to bounce. Direction: Left</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div id="bouncy3">Click here to bounce. Direction: Right</div></td>
    <td><div id="bouncy4">Click here to bounce. Direction: Down</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input id="bounceAll" type="button" value="Click to Bounce All!"/>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    padding:5px;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
#bouncy1 {
    background-color:#FFEE88;
}
#bouncy2 {
    background-color:#EE88FF;
}
#bouncy3 {
    background-color:#EE8888;
}
#bouncy4 {
    background-color:#88EEFF;
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function(){

    //Add bounce effect on Click of the DIV
    $('#bouncy1').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { times:5 }, 300);
    });

    $('#bouncy2').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'left', times:5 }, 300);
    });

    $('#bouncy3').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'right', times:5 }, 300);
    });

    $('#bouncy4').click(function () {
          $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'down', times:5 }, 300);
    });

    //Bounce all DIVs on click of button
    $("#bounceAll").click(function(){
        $("div").click();
    });
});
```

#### Demo at [Fantastic Bouncy Effect using jQuery/JavaScript](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-bounce-effect-bounce-html-js/)

#### For your JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click();
});
```

#### In your JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    function bounceDiv(){
        $("#six").effect("bounce", { times:3, distance:20 }, 400);
    }
    setInterval('bounceDiv()', 1000);
});
```

#### You forgot the `'`s! :(

**Source: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-bounce-effect-bounce-html-js/**

Comment: In your case, for the JavaScript, you can use onload function: `$(document).ready(function(){$("div").click();});`

Answer (score 1):

this will work 100%

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function bounceDiv(){
    $("#six").effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    setInterval('bounceDiv()',5000);
});
</script>
```

Enjoy :)